# Setting image height & width at run time by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, height, width

I want to set an image's width and height at run time (as per device, such as desktop, mobile, iPad, and etc...)

How can I do this?

Comment: As per device, do you refer to their display size/resolution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a handheld device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)